# Agent hidden file ".certificates" - documentation, options?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We ran into an issue where all but one of our on-prem build servers were not able to download a third party file as part of a widely used extension [purposely omitting the name for security reasons], and the only way we could get it to work was to modify the .certificates file in the agent install directory.

I was able to find what I think is the [source file in github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent/AgentCertificateManager.cs) - but there are no comments or documentation available.  We stumbled onto this because one of our five build machines had this file [and worked], but the other four didn't.  Does anybody know what generates this file and what these options are for?

File contents:

```
{
  "skipServerCertValidation": true,
  "caCert": null,
  "clientCert": null,
  "clientCertPrivatekey": null,
  "clientCertArchive": null,
  "clientCertPasswordLookupKey": null
}
```

Comment: Instead of turning off certificate security, it's better to ensure that your agent has the right certificate chains in it's cert store. See: https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/main/docs/checks/sslcert.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody know what generates this file and what these options are for?

When you config the agent with `--sslskipcertvalidation`, the `.certificates` file will be created with the contents you shared, and the agent will ignore SSL server certificate validation error. You can refer [Work with SSL server certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/certificate?view=azure-devops-2022#work-with-ssl-server-certificate) for more details.

```
config.cmd --sslskipcertvalidation
```